# Could you say that in an orchestra some instruments talk to each other?

Tags: orchestra

I'm asking this question in regards to a website project we're starting about a classical orchestra. I'd like to know if there's a sort of conversation between instruments/musicians in a symphony, for example, and if you could give specific examples. The general idea would be to show this conversation/exchange on a website, visually and through other methods if possible. I'm staying vague as the project is in its early stages.

Thank you!
Alain

ps: Thank you for your amazing answers. Unfortunately we can't reply to answers and thank people personally here but I hope that editing the original question is accepted.

Comment: If you mean sharing melodies then yes, you could say so.

Comment: This sort of "conversation" was one of the basic principles of classical music (if by "classical" you mean the time period of say 1750 - 1830). In the educational system of the time, the foundation subjects of a liberal arts education (the "trivium") were grammar, logic, and rhetoric, and the second level (the "quadrivium") consisted of arithmetic, geometry, music, and astronomy.

Comment: @alephzero Can you explain some more how the seven liberal arts connect to this "conversation"?

Answer (score 3):

Edward Klorman, a music theorist at McGill University, has been researching this exact question. For a nice introduction to his thought process, check out [this](https://vimeo.com/137507825) 10-minute video, a brief description of which is:

> Comparisons between the string quartet and artful conversation have flourished since the genre’s birth. If a quartet performance resembles stylized social intercourse, each player may be understood to enact the role of an individual persona engaged in the discourse.

He's also got a book, the website for which can be found [here](http://mozartsmusicoffriends.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the best place to start would be with the fugue form, in which a theme is first introduced and then repeated and developed across two or more voices. In some instances, there can be a recapitulation, or the piece can simply return to the initial theme in the original (tonic) key. While the best-known examples are some of the keyboard compositions by J.S. Bach (such as *Das Wohltempiert Klavier*), Haydn used the form as well (see, for example, the *String Quartets, Op.20*). On an even grander scale, you could look at Haydn's composition, *The Creation*, with the fugue form being used in *Verzweiflung, Wut und Schrecken*.

Answer (score 2):

Every orchestral group or instrument has its role, its voice, and creating a conversation between these voices makes a music. This of course does not work with some types of modern or contemporary music, where this conversation is intentionally destroyed ;-)

Listen to the beginning of the New World Symphony:

After the introduction played by strings there is an interruption by the french horn around 1:00 and then the melody is taken by the winds. Definitely a conversation between two groups.

Or you can find composers who were deriving their music directly from human's speech. My favourite is Leoš Janáček ;-)